# Search Data from multiple tables laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to search multiple data from two related tables. To be specific I want to get only "name column" from the users table and the rest of the columns from the posts table. But whenever I tried to search it prints the following error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Below is my user model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Mail\NewUserWelcomeMail;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email','phone', 'username', 'password', 
        'admin', 'address', 'description', 'approved_at',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

And post model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

And my Controller

```
public function showcampaign(User $user) {
    $q = Input::get( 'q' );

    if( !empty( $q ) ) {
        $showcampaign = User::join('posts','posts.user_id','users.id')
            ->where('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('caption','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('duration','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('amount','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->get();

        if(count($showcampaign) > 0) {
            return view('admin.campaignreport', ['show' => $showcampaign]);
        } else { 
            return redirect('/campaignreport')->with('status', 'No Details found. Try to search again !');
        }
    } else { 
        $showcampaign = Post::all();

        return view('admin.campaignreport')->with('show', $showcampaign);
    }
}
```

Please help thanks

Comment: can you specify the laravel version

Comment: i am using laravel 5.8 @Manojkiran.A

Comment: @Owdenpk You need to use `table_name.column_name` syntax in the where query.

Comment: from the error it seems you are getting this error on the view file but not in the controller. right??

Comment: yes, i get when i search from the view

Comment: Thanks very much @zahidhasanemon now i get a clue where the problem is. i checked my view and find out i was calling name with @foreach($show as $show)
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{$show->user->name}}
        </td> instead of $show->name.

Answer (score 5):

As you have already declared the relations within the Model So you can use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_whereHas) and also [orWhereHas](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_orWhereHas)

So

```
$showcampaign = SampleReception::query()
            ->whereHas('posts',function(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) use ($q){
                return $query->where('caption', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
                ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
                ->orWhere('duration', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%') 
                ->orWhere('amount', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%');
            })
            ->orWhere('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->get();
```

For any issues leave a comment

Comment: it still prints the same error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Comment: can you post the table structure of posts and users table

Answer (score 2):

Try.. use `where` instead of `orwhere`

```
$showcampaign = User::join('posts','posts.user_id','users.id')
                ->where('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
                ->Where('caption','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
                ->Where('description','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
                ->Where('duration','LIKE','%'.$q.'%') 
                ->Where('amount','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->get();
```

Comment: please mark as a helpful if you get your answer THANK YOU @Owdenpk

Comment: where and orwhere has nothing to do with the error message

Comment: if I tried to replace orWhere with where, it does not match any information from both tables even if with an existing records - @VikasKatariya

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use a reference table for where clause.

```
$showcampaign = User::join('posts','posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('users.name','LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('posts.caption', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('posts.description', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('posts.duration', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%') 
            ->orWhere('posts.amount', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->get();
```

If you define relationship correctly then use:

```
$showcampaign = SampleReception::with(['posts' => function($query) use($q) {
            return $query->where('caption', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('duration', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%') 
            ->orWhere('amount', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%');
        }])
        ->orWhere('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit senjaliya. I have tried adding references as you recommended and the error has gone, but now it can match any data from both tables. Even if i try to search an existing record, it can't match

Answer (score 0):

I use scope query to create search functions. It makes my code more flexible and easy to understand.
Here is how you can do this.

In your "user" Model, you have to write "scopeFunctionName". you can write any functionName with scope. And in your Controller, you can simply call this function whenever you need as functionName(). and pass here your search term from request as functionName(request(['search']))

And now as you have declared relations for these tables to search data from related tables, try using this code in your user Model

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
{
    /* 
    Hey $query! whenever u get 'search term' in URL, call the function.
    If ['search'] exists or != null, then pass its value to the function
    else return false and don't execute the $query. If value exists,
    Then the function will execute the query and returns a result.
    */
    $query->when(
        $filters['search'] ?? false,
        fn ($query, $search) =>
        $query
            ->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($search) {
                return $query
                    ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            })
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('caption', 'like', '%', . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%', . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('id', $search)
    );
}
```

And in Controller, you can pass the value to the scope function as:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('posts.index', [
        'show' => Post::all()->filter(request(['search']))->with('user')
    ]);
}
```

Note: The code above has not been tested but it might solve your problem.